# How to query specific rows order by multiply result

Tags: mysql

I have a product table with commission column. I want to compare the product and sort by commission result. Is it possible to do so? Here I have :

```
id  price   com% (com)
3   3500    23   (805)
4   3800    23   (874)
30  3800    25   (950)
31  4000    25   (1000)
32  3500    22   (770)
```

According to the `com` column. I expect the result to sort from `31,30,4,3 and 1` accordingly. All I can thinking of is this query.

```
select * from excursion_db order by exc_com desc
```

Only sort by the commission (`com` column). Which may cause an error when there's a high `com%` but low `price`. Eventually the `com` might lower than the higher price but less `com%`.

So, how to get the specify row order by the sum of `price*com%` desc?

**Please note that : The `(com)` column is not exists in the table. I write up here to compare the total commission.**

Comment: You can use comma in order by price, com

Comment: `select *,`price*com%` as srt from excursion_db order by srt desc` I think this is you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from excursion_db order by price * `com%` desc
```